# What is the proper terminology for a waterfall or stream that loops back round in a cyclic manner?

Tags: water

For example if water falls down a waterfall then it eventually reaches the very top again to fall back down again.

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science Stack Exchange! What you're describing is not possible in a natural environment because water doesn't flow uphill. Do you have some specific example that you're trying to understand?

Comment: i guess this is what the OP ask about https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_snHyCh3V8 having to guess is a reason for this question to be closed.

Comment: @kwinkunks It doesn't have to be a waterfall as that's highly vertical with a cliff. It could be something else like a river, stream, or sea.

Comment: @desbest You're going to have to provide some specific examples, like a photo or video, or maybe a location on Earth. E.g. see Trond's suggestion. Is that the kind of thing you're talking about?

Comment: Perpetual motion.

Comment: The only way you'll get water to flow uphill is by forcing it.  That can be wind, hydrostatic pressure, manmade pump, etc.  (I can envision some crazy scenario where water flows downhill, then due to very special geology and water addition [precip/inflow], is forced back up through a favorable pathway in the rock??)  But it likely wouldn't last long term or be very large (and it isn't truly cyclic, since much of the returning water wouldn't be the same water)

Comment: What if there is no uphill level and there's only the ground level. Would there be a term for it in that instance?

Answer (score 2):

The proper technical term is an [Escher *Waterval*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_(M._C._Escher)).

[image]